# While Updating Firestore Data timestamp is null

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I have a realtime listener for orders when I accept order there is one field updates named "status" and another field is added named "datetime_accepted"

**Here is Listener for monitoring document change**

```
db.collection('ORDERS').where('status', '==', 'a').orderBy('datetime_accepted')
  .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
      if (change.type === 'added') {
        var id = change.doc.id
        var snapJSON = JSON.stringify(change.doc.data());
        var orderOBJ = JSON.parse(snapJSON);
        orderOBJ.oid = id;
        var confirm_datetime = new Date(orderOBJ.datetime_accepted.seconds*1000).toLocaleString();
```

**This is a Separate Function which I am running to update the fields**

```
db.collection("ORDERS").doc(id).update({
    "datetime_accepted": firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    "status": "a"
})
```

When Status of order is changed the error happened but after refreshing the timestamp works fine  again
This Problem is only in realtime updation in timestamp

[image]

Comment: I don't see how that error would happen with the code you're showing here.  Please edit the question to be clear about where you are observing the error in your code.  The stack trace suggests script.js line 198.

Comment: On Stack Overflow you should **edit the question** to show all relevant details.  Do not provide links.  Use the edit button at the bottom of the question.

Comment: @DougStevenson Updated

Comment: You should also copy text into the question instead of showing screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior.  There are two things to keep in mind:

1. Server timestamps don't have an actual value until the document actually reaches the server
2. Firestore document listeners will trigger immediately when a document is changed, before the document reaches the server.

This means that your listener is receiving the update **before** it reaches the server, and that snapshot is not going to have a timestamp in it.

Your code will need to check for this specific case by handling the undefined timestamp value.  [Read more about how server timestamps work.](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/the-secrets-of-firestores-fieldvalue-servertimestamp-revealed-29dd7a38a82b)

Comment: Let me read the document and I will get back to you if there is a problem

Comment: if (!data.datetime_accepted && change.doc.metadata.hasPendingWrites) {
            const ts = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now()
            console.log(`timestamp: ${ts} (estimated)`)
        }
        else {
            console.log(`timestamp: ${data.datetime_accepted} (actual)`)
        }

I am getting the actual value of timestamp how I can update my timestamp with actual value?

Comment: If you have another question, please post it separately with the new code that you're working with.